# Variables in effective windows batch file for deployment?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've played around quite a bit now, and can't seem to get variables to work in a batch file, when executing commands. So, can anyone tell me if this is possible, and what is wrong with these lines of code:

```
set THE_DB = myAwesomeDb
set OUTPUT_FILE = .\db\mydb.sql
mysqldump -u root --opt %THE_DB% > %OUTPUT_FILE%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put spaces around the equal symbol.

```
set THE_DB=myAwesomeDb
set OUTPUT_FILE=.\db\mydb.sql
mysqldump -u root --opt %THE_DB% > %OUTPUT_FILE%
```

Comment: You rock! Thanks. You dont maybe know how make a a seperate file with lots of variables in it, that I can then include into other files?!

Comment: Try to put all your set commands in another batch file and call it in your main batch with the call command.